# How can I spawn objects in a given volume/area 3d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I was given a task by my teacher to make a script to spawn object RANDOMLY in a given AREA 3D either in a rectangle or in a sphere, I know how to do that  but have no idea how to make it choose random place in the area.

Thanks.

Comment: What area/volume? A rect, cube, sphere, arbitrary volume? Sounds like you are looking for [`Random.insideUnitSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitSphere.html) .. multiply by radius -> done

Comment: Please also read here about [Homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Okay  I'll see the webs and I want a rectangle place were they spawn thanka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measure the range (x-axis, y-axis, z-axis) in Unity, and then use time to control how often it is generated. These are randomly generated codes, don't forget to drag the prefab to the cube

```
public GameObject cube;//Define a cube to store the prefab to be randomly generated
private float t1, t2;// Control how often to generate by time

void Start()
{
    t1 = 0;//time when the game starts
}

void Update()
{
    t2 = Time.fixedTime;//The time when the game progresses to a certain position
    if (t2 - t1 >= 2)
    {
        x = Random.Range(-50,50);//Specify the range in the x-axis direction
        z = Random.Range(-50,50);//Specify the range in the z-axis direction
        //Specify the scope according to the actual situation of your own scene
        Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(x, 0.5f, z), Quaternion.identity);// Randomly generate objects (prefab, generated position, orientation).
        t1 = t2;//Every time it is generated, let t1=t2

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay illl ook into this thanks

Comment: I also found information on the Internet, I really hope it can help you.

Comment: I mean this works but the z and x is it possible to make it spawn around/in the block / gameobject not the world?

Comment: because it spawns them in the start of theworld not near object